# sudo apt install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0 command not working

Tags: apt

I am using the following command:

sudo apt install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0

But, getting the following error:

Package libxcb-xinerama0 has no installation candidates

When I used the command 'apt-cache search libxcb-xinerama', prior to the above command, I didn't receive any output.

I ticked the check box 'Source code' in the 'Downloadable from the Internet' section in 'Software and Updates' dialog box, but I am getting 'Error while refreshing cache'.

Comment: Packages are built for specific releases; you've not told us yours, thus we cannot specifically help you. I did a search and found results for many releases (*including my own & all supported releases, but yours may differ*) so are you using a supported release?  (we can't know as you've not told us).  I'd return to basics; ie. `sudo apt update` & check for all expected lines being present, none missing, no warnings etc.. and if you need package help, please provide your release (*it's required detail for specific help*).

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release`or even `$ source /etc/os-release ; echo $PRETTY_NAME`